# Как сделать выпадающий список с городами и регионами через API

Tags: javascript, api

В интернет магазине нужно сделать выбор города, где живет продавец

Нужно сделать выпадающие меню с областями\регионами, там человек выбирает свой регион, потом появляется другой список с районами, потом с городами\деревнями
Так же нужен поиск

Не могу найти подходящего API
Возможно плохо гуглил)

Comment: Можно использовать гораздо более удобный функционал - Строку ФИАС в `dadata`, хотя и Ваш вариант тоже работает.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо, вот конкретная ссылка на API. Очень удобно)

https://dadata.ru/suggestions/